# Como verificar se um conjunto de caracteres existe na coluna da tabela?

Tags: sql, operador-like

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```php
|id|nome                 |
|1 |Lucas Santos da Silva|
|2 |Igor Julião Gonçalves|
|3 |Mário Marques Silva  |
|4 |David Silva          |
```

Como poderia pegar todas as pessoas que tem **Silva** no nome?

```php
$string = "Silva";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome IN('{$string}');
```

Comment: Não poderia usar o operador `LIKE`?

Comment: Poderia informar qual é o banco de dados, pois existe um artificio que pode melhorar expressivamente o tempo de consulta e cada BDMS o implementa de uma forma.

Comment: o nome do banco é ```cde3```.

Comment: Fica difícil apresentar uma solução realmente eficiente sem saber o nome da engine de banco de dados, eu pesquisei no google *cde3 database* não encontrei nada. As soluções apresentadas tem complexidade de tempo O(n x m) onde *n* é o número de registros e *m* é o total de caracteres a ser pesquisado enquanto uma solução usando nativamente [inverted index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) possui complexidade de tempo O(log n).

Comment: Ahhh, pensei que você tava perguntando o nome do meu banco de dados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para retornar todas as pessoas que tem Silva em qualquer lugar do texto, use o operador [`LIKE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp).

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome LIKE '%Silva%'
```

Fique atento ao custo de performance dessa operação.

Comment: Concordo o operador LIKE pode consumir muito  em uma consulta dependendo do tamanho da entidade ao  qual se  faz a busca.

Answer (score 4):

Complementando, utilize também a opção `Upper`/`Lower` para melhor utilização.

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE upper(nome) LIKE upper('%Silva%').
```

Assim você garante que o resultado será `'Silva'`, independente de como você escrever ele (`SiLvA`, `sILvA`, etc).